# Create a Network listener (Interface) that reacts to change in network state

Tags: android, listener

How to create an **interface** which **listens to network state** and can be implemented in any class to take appropriate action.

I've read examples of **broadcast receiver** but none solved my problem.

Also if there is any way a receiver (**listening to network**) can be used to execute some code within a class.

Thanks for the help.

> Resultant class should look like this-

```
class Main implements NetworkChangeListener{
...
..
.

//this code runs on network change
@override
public void onNetworkChange(boolean isConnected) {
            if(isConnected){
    //call desired method or code
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a class that implements ConnectionManager and extends BroadcastListener to check for network connectivity and broadcast its state.

Comment: @eee How to respond to this event in some class that already has a purpose. Suppose i have a Fragment and i want to replace the fragment on network change.

Comment: http://thiranjith.com/2011/03/31/how-to-monitor-network-connectivity-in-android/

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818734/Article-Android-Connectivity